# How do I solve "Reactive<_>' is ambiguous" error in tableView context

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I have a `method` that returns a `Single`:

```
func getEventStatus() throws -> Single<EventModel?> {
    return try mainService.getEventStatus()
}
```

And I tried to `bind` it to a `tableView` but got an `error` saying that it doesn't work on `Singles`, so I tried adding `.asObservable()` but now I get the `error`

> Expression type 'Reactive<_>' is ambiguous without more context

I have tried to look up what it means but there doesn't seem to be any consistency to what the `error` means, or I can't seem to apply it to my case. This is what the `bind` looks like:

```
viewModel.getEventStatus().asObservable().bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: EventLogTableViewCell.identifier, cellType: EventLogTableViewCell.self)) { row, data, cell in
    cell.viewModel = data
}.disposed(by:disposeBag)
```

As the `method` `throws` I added `do { try catch{} }` but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the signature of your method.

The `getEventStatus()` method only emits one `EventModel` and even that is an `Optional`.

The `items(cellIdentifier:cellType:)` method requires an Array of things.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, but how do I convert it to an array? I tried `try? viewModel.getEventStatus().asObservable().toArray().bind....` but then it says that "'PrimitiveSequence<SingleTrait, [EventModel?]>' has no member 'bind'"

Comment: Put brackets around EventModel and get rid of the question mark.